# Why do we use the rotating wave picture to make approxiamations in open quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, open-quantum-systems

Why do we use the rotating wave picture to make approxiamations in open quantum systems? I understand why we use the Heisenberg picture when switching to the interaction picture. But why rotating picture?

Comment: I am familiar with the rotating wave *approximation*, but haven't heard of the rotating wave *picture*. Could you explain the difference, if there is any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Fleming and his colleges have a nice article about this matter.

See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1749

As a very short answer I should say that
We have two distinct rotating-waveapproximations:

1) The pre-trace RWA is an approximation performed on the interaction Hamiltonian before the en-vironment is traced out which yields a somewhat modified Hamiltonian dynamics from which the reduced dynamics can be derived.

2)The post-trace RWA is performed on the master equation for the reduced density matrix after the environment has already been traced out.

You can also take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7350.pdf .
They studied the dynamics of a two-level quantum system interact
ing with a single frequency electromagnetic field and a stochastic magnetic field, with and without making the rotating wave approximation!

Comment: Thank you so much! These papers are very insightful and useful!

Comment: I am very happy that you liked them. Let's thank Fleming and Band for their contribution toward the field!